# How to upload video and images to LinkedIn via REST API?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

We are developing an application in which user uploads the content and media in the form of image/video. The media gets stored in Azure. As mentioned in the share API, we are just passing the link as a part of the comment. Although the image is visible, it is seen as a link, which on clicked opens in another window. 
[image: Image as link]

In case of video, no preview is visible. It is seen just as a link.
[image: No video preview, only link]

The API we are using is:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Is there any other API for this which is part of Partner Program?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any Partner Program

Image uploading you need to put

```
"title" => "your title",
"submitted-url" => 'your website url' 
"submitted-image-url" => 'your image full http path'
```

so you can see images from submitted-image-url and submitted-url can be your website url that is compulsory so this way your url will not open popup image

Video uploading you need to create a dynamic page on you site there will some meta tags for url and img like og:url, og:img ...
and html video tag there in src you can put video url..

```
"title" => "your title",
"submitted-url" => 'dynamic created url with ids or timestamp for remove caching'
```

if meta is perfect on you page then from meta image will show as a preview in linkedin and when you click on image then your website page will open where you already have html video tag 
so on your page video page video will play

you can create meta tags and page like buffer

https://video.buffer.com/v/5a82df3df78c53d21249f680

Thanks